# Magento 2 error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'quoteData' of undefined

Tags: checkout, quote, onestepcheckout

In my magento 2 Onestep Checkout page in not displayed because of error. I am not recognizing the cause.
file path is `pub/static/frontend/Vendor/mobile/en_US/Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote.js`
[image]

Can I get Help? Thank you in advance

Comment: can you check log error ...

Comment: @Mohit Patel, Thank you for response in error log am getting  `The element 'checkout.cart.item.renderers' already has a child with alias 'virtual' in /home/www/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php:611` error

Comment: check this link :- https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Checkout-Page-not-loading-and-getting-blank-page/td-p/96257